# What is the appeal of not Re-incarnating?

Tags: mind, reincarnation

I understand that after death, the mind may move to a different plane of existance to be re-incarnated, but what is the appeal of moving to a different plane after death? Is it wrong to say that I'm satisfied with where I'm currently at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Buddha clearly rebuked the idea of consciousness/mind that runs and wanders on [from birth to birth] in [Mahatanhasankhaya Sutta (MN 38)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html).

> "Exactly so, lord. As I understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, it is just this consciousness that runs and wanders on, not another."
>
> "Which consciousness, Sāti, is that?"
>
> "This speaker, this knower, lord, that is sensitive here & there to the ripening of good & evil actions."
>
> "And to whom, worthless man, do you understand me to have taught the Dhamma like that? Haven't I, in many ways, said of dependently co-arisen consciousness, 'Apart from a requisite condition, there is no coming-into-play of consciousness'? But you, through your own poor grasp, not only slander us but also dig yourself up [by the root] and produce much demerit for yourself. That will lead to your long-term harm & suffering."

---

Birth(*Jati*) is caused by becomming (*bhava*).

> "Ananda, if there were no kamma ripening in the sensuality-property, would sensuality-becoming be discerned?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "Thus kamma is the field, consciousness the seed, and craving the moisture. The consciousness of living beings hindered by ignorance & fettered by craving is established in/tuned to a lower property. Thus there is the production of renewed becoming in the future.

[Bhava Sutta: Becoming (AN 3.76)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.076.than.html)

Comment: good answer. i guess you could say that a mind is recreated, tho?

Answer (score 2):

what wrong with being satisfied with current situations is that current situations don't stay with way.  They deteriorate and will break apart with 100% certainty.

If there was no death, there would be no Buddhism.

Just to be clear, Buddhism is not about leaving current situation to be in a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You may be satisfied with where you are currently at, but sooner or later you are going to want something better. That’s human nature. You may not want to die, but it is going to come your way sooner or later. That’s life, @tuskiomi.

But there is a deathless happiness out there if you are willing to work towards it. For that firstly you need to get skillful in how you go about things in the present moment. It calls for a different kind of skillset. The problem is that most people in the world don’t have a correct idea about their skills. They just do not know of their latent skills that are helpful in realizing life. That is why you and I are satisfied just by living their lives eating, drinking, and enjoying.

It never occur to us to see into these latent talents that can be developed in this very life. It is not our fault that things are such. The French would say “Ce La Vie” – such as the way life goes. That is why we are still in a journey of been born, getting sick, getting old, and dying again and again (Samsara).

Answer (score 1):

"but what is the appeal of moving to a different plane after death?"

**Reincarnation has a forced nature due to [Twelve Nidanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Nid%C4%81nas).**
I would recommend looking at the Tibetan Book of the Dead for further anecdotal information on how we are drawn to reincarnating into certain destinies and then get sucked into that life (pre-birth).

**Buddhism has as its purpose to stop this forced birth-and-death** and control the process like a Tibetan lama, Enlightened master, or bodhisattva is able to, going where he is most needed in the universe, not where his karma (attachments/fears) compels him.

"Is it wrong to say that I'm satisfied with where I'm currently at?"

It isn't wrong but don't think that it is possible to stay in an existence forever. Even if you live 100 thousand years as a golden immortal (one of the immortals that is discussed in Surangama Sutra) stretching out your existence for as long as possible through various health regimen, eventually it will end and when you reflect back on that time spent as an immortal, it will feel like a flash of lightning...

**Do what you came here to do and be ready to go.**

This is why it is best to become a Buddha... the end result is this: dwell in your dharmakaya nature and emanate a new body where you are needed for as long as needed, for the highest good of all... at this point you have no attachment to staying or going.